# Flask form test fails for some reason

Tags: python, flask, pytest, wtforms

I recently created tests for my Flask app.

I am using Flask-WTF for my forms. I have the following form in one of my routes:

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
class URLForm(FlaskForm):
    url = StringField('url', validators=[InputRequired(), URL(require_tld=True)],
                      render_kw={"placeholder": "Paste URL here"})
```

I have the following test:

```
def test_valid_link(self, app):
    """Valid link"""
    form = URLForm(url='https://example.com')

    assert form.validate()
```

This test fails, even though when running my app, the form accepts the same url.

My test app has CSRF disabled so that shouldn't be an issue (I also tried disabling CSRF when initializing the form in the tests)

Furthermore, the following outputs might help:

```
>>> form.url
<input id="url" name="url" placeholder="Paste URL here" required type="text" value="https://example.com">
>>> form.data
{'url': 'https://example.com'}
>>> form.validate()
False
>>> form.errors
{'url': ['This field is required.']}
```